# Microsoft access iff statement

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've been making an award system in ms access but trying to use the if statement for 2 distinct parameters, i.e. in one class top 3 students get a different amount from what the top 3 students of another class might get. All the data of all classes is in one table.

See:

```
Student ID  Class ID    Average Rank    Awards
1111    Form4            77.79166667        2   
1189    Form4                    105        1   
1222    Form4            73.41666667        3   
1234    Form4            69.95833333        4   
1235    Form 3           77.16666667        3   
1236    Form 3                72.875        4   
1258    Form 3           82.54166667        1   
1333    Form 3                 77.25        2   
1367    Form 2           56.54545455        4   
1445    Form 2           75.66666667        2   
1447    Form 2           75.72727273        1   
1465    Form 2           74.18181818        3   
1523    Form 1           76.18181818        3   
1542    Form 1           75.51515152        4   
1552    Form 1           79.03030303        2   
1555    Form 1           79.63636364        1
```

at the awards column when creating a query the build formula I use i.e.  `IIf([Rank]=1,1100)` gives all student IDs ranked 1 an award of 1100 but I want only form 1 student IDs to get 1100 and the others ranked 1st with different award values please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
IIF([ClassID] <> "Form 1", IIf([Rank]=1,500), IIf([Rank]=1,1100))
```

Obviously, you will have to edit the award amount since you didn't specify what you were giving, but the logic should hold true.

Comment: entered what u asked  but still getting all no. 1 ranked students getting 1100 but I want different award for different no 1 ranks in different classes

Answer (score 0):

If this gets a bit more complicated, you can write a function in VBA (in any code module in the 'modules' section), and use it in the query:

`ExpressionName: evaluateAward(ClassID, Rank)`

In the function, you can then use nested `select case` statements. This may be much better for readability.